# Grails 3 avoid restart changing scaffolding templates

Tags: templates, grails, scaffolding

Hi does anyone know if there is a way to not restart the grails app after one is doning changes to the scaffolding templates?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You mean to refresh the templates _without_ restarting the container, or to ignore changes completely?

Comment: Hi Christopher Will. I would like to refresh the templates without restarting the container...